# React app not displaying anything but a black screen

Tags: reactjs

I set up a new project with react but all I get is a blank screen. Am I making a mistake when importing/exporting my code? Do I need to use index.html to import my index.js?

App.js

```
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import Register from './Components/Register';
import CreatePost from './Components/CreatePost';
import AllPost from './Components/AllPost';
import NotFound from './Components/NotFound';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
        <Navigate from='/CreatePost' to='/Register' />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}>
            <Home />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path='/Register' component={Register}>
            <Register /> 
          </Route>

          <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login}>
            <Login />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path='/CreatePost' component={CreatePost}>
            <CreatePost />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path='/AllPost' component={AllPost}>
            <AllPost />
          </Route>

          <Route component=
            {NotFound}>

          </Route>

          

        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It's worth mentioning I am not getting any errors and my components seem do be working properly

Comment: Do you import BrowserRouter, Routes, Route etc. from 'react-router-dom' ? I don't see any import...

Answer (score 1):

You are doing just a small mistake here

Change this

```
<Route exact path='/AllPost' component={AllPost}>
        <AllPost />
      </Route>
```

To this

```
<Route exact path='/AllPost' element={<AllPost/>}>
</Route>
```

Do this with every Route See if it works

Comment: This should work

Comment: I tried it out but it looks the same. The console is giving me ```Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>``` and ```The above error occurred in the <Routes> component:```

Comment: you have used Navigate inside a Routes only Route components can be a child of Routes